# Using Backbone.Router for a slideshow

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm creating a slideshow using Backbone.js. My slideshow view is finished, each slide is a model and all the models are inside a collection. Now I want to apply a little hashbang magic to my slideshow :-)

This is my code structure

1. application.js
2. models/slideshow/slide.js
3. collections/slideshow/slides.js
4. views/slideshow.js

In application.js I create my router:

```
var App = {};
App.Modules = {
    Views: {},
    Models: {},
    Collections: {}
};
App.slideshow = undefined; // Use this to maintain state between calls.
App.router = (function() {
    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            'slideshow/:id/:page': 'slideshow'
        },
        slideshow: function(id, page) {
            // Whenever this route handler triggers, I want to either:
            //     1) Instantiate the slideshow, or:
            //     2) Change the page on an already instantiated slideshow
            if (App.slideshow && App.slideshow.options.id === id) {
                App.slideshow.goToPage(page);
            } else {
                App.slideshow = new App.Modules.Views.Slideshow({
                    id: id,
                    page: page
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return new Router;
})();

// Using jQuery's document ready handler.
$(function() {
    Backbone.history.start({
        root: '/'
    });
});
```

This works as I expect. My slideshow works as an overlay so no matter what page it's instantiated on, it will just show itself on top of the existing document.

My first question is how do I close the slideshow (App.slideshow.close()); when the user hits the browser back button or navigates to another hashbang, which doesn't follow the /slideshow/:id/:page syntax?

My last question has to do with the 'navigate' method in Routers. In my slideshow view, I make sure to update the hash fragment whenever the page changes. This is what I do in my view:

```
pageChange: function(page) {
    App.router.navigate('slideshow/' + this.options.id + '/' + page, false);
}
```

This makes sure the fragment gets updated so that the user at any point can copy the URL and it will open on the same page. The problem is that my 'slideshow' method in my instantiated router triggers even though I pass false in the second 'navigate' parameter (triggerRoute). Why is this?

Comment: So, I've solved my first question (please let me know if this can be done in a cleaner): In my router I create a new route: '*other': 'defaultRoute'. And then in my defaultRoute handler I do: if (App.slideshow) App.slideshow.close();

Comment: Are you sure you aren't calling your `slideshow` method elsewhere? Having the rest of the view can help as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I've figured it out. Please let me know if there are cleaner ways to do this.

After reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/hh377172 I saw you can do this in Backbone.js:

```
var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '*other': 'defaultRoute'
    },
    defaultRoute: function() {
        if (App.slideshow) App.slideshow.close();
    }
};
```

This makes sure everything that doesn't match /slideshow/:id/:page will close the slideshow if it's been instantiated.

With regard to 'navigate' apparently it's because I did `App.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.events);` Apparently, I have to do:

```
App.vent = {};
_.extend(App.vent, Backbone.events);
```